# Modifying superfish menus to gives extra block of data

Tags: 7, navigation

I am using superfish menus and it works fine and i want to add extra column in superfish menu which will display some stand alone data. how do i alter superfish menu to do this. I have shown in image what i need to do.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure you can achieve this with Superfish without a major hack to the module. Try using [OM Maximenu](http://drupal.org/project/om_maximenu) which can create menus with all other module blocks you want as attachments, modules like views, slideshow, menu, user, nice menus, quicktabs, and custom blocks with tables, lists, images, videos, etc.

[image]

Comment: i could not have asked for a better solution. Thanks a lot :).